# Storage de HTML5 admite 5MB por variable o por pagina web?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, local-storage

Tengo una duda, estoy empezando a usar el almacenamiento web HTML localStorage pero no entiendo si la capacidad que acepta es por pagina web o por varible. Espero me puedan sacar de dudas, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las especificaciones sugieren que sea de 5MB **por página web**. Pero esto no te garantiza que sea así en todos los navegadores.
Si necesitas tanto espacio deberías averiguar si no te conviene más usar otro tipo de almacenamiento como [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup).

[Más info aquí](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa?hl=es)

Comment: Wow no había escuchado de eso, pero estoy leyendo y está muy interesante, básicamente tu servidor en tu web.

Comment: Pero ojo con qué datos guardas ahí, ya que el usuario podría llegar a verlos. No guardes datos de otros usuarios, etc...

Comment: Eso estuve leyendo. Muchas gracias. Saludos